# MySQL datetime request in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

how do I show the time and date properly, it's only showing the year in the code I did

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row["nome"];
echo " | ";
echo $row["descricao"];
echo " | ";
echo $row["urgencia"];
echo " | ";
echo $row["id"]+;
echo " | ";
echo $row["datahora"]+"/n";
?> <br></br> <?php
}
```

Comment: The "datahora" means: datetime

Comment: where is the query ? we need to see your $result, Also provide sample data

Comment: $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM   suporte";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: provide some `datahora` values from table

Comment: Provide some data from the database esp datahora

Comment: I use this to fill the table

$sql =mysql_query("INSERT INTO suporte(name, description, urgency, dateandtime) VALUES('$name', '$description', '$urgency', NOW())");

i change the names because they are in portuguese here

Comment: what is the **datatype** for the column `datahora`. we just need to see if your table actually has the full datetime ('YYYY','MM','DD') information, then we can figure out its the mistake in code or query

Comment: but when I try to print the values that i got with the NOW() it displays only the 2015 for an example the value in the table is 2015-04-06 08:55:32

Comment: by the way, if you meant `+` as concatenation, its supposed to be `.`

Comment: the + was just in the wrong place :s

Comment: Can you try echo $row["datahora"] . "/n";

Comment: such a small mistake... sorry I'm just starting now in php

Comment: why that was happening?

Comment: + is the addition operator so were trying to add your date plus newline, which equates to nothing good. "." concatonates the date and the newline. Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: thank you all for the time!!